# IBM MQ Topic lookup returning default destination always

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

Problem statement :

We have 2 topics setup on the dev queue manager (USTCMN01)

One for our dev usage (EDM.BIRS.RDP.ONEPPM.TO_RDA) and the other for SIT (EDM.BIRS.RDP.S1.ONEPPM.TO_RDA)

When publishing to our SIT topic, our consumer queue (EDM.BIRS.RDP.S1.RDA.FROM_ONEPPM) isn’t getting the message on the other end.
We are not getting any exceptions while producing the message.

Issue :

When we try to look up for SIT topic in our Java client , it is getting resolved to DEV topic , in spite of the fact that we are supplying  a destination which is dedicated for SIT.

The IBM MQ infrastructure is handled by a different team

Java client Code

The routine produceWorkflowMessage() in the attached file is responsible for publishing messages

```
package com.cs.srp.rdp.omb;

import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantClass;

 import javax.jms.*;
 import javax.naming.InitialContext;
 import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
 import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.security.KeyStore;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Hashtable;
 import java.util.List; 
 import java.util.Properties;

 import static javax.naming.Context.*;

 public class OMBTopicPublisher {


private InitialContext ic = null;
private Connection connection;
private Session session;
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

private Connection createConnection() throws JMSException {
    String providerCredentials = "aGMk643R";
    String providerUrl = "ldap://esd-qa.csfb.net/ou=MQ,ou=Services,dc=csfb,dc=CS-Group,dc=com";
    String keyStoreFile = "C:\\Balaji\\workspace\\workflowrda\\src\\main\\properties\\jks\\test\\keystore.jks";
    String password = "rFzv0UOS";
    String queueManagerConnectionFactory = "cn=USTCMN01_CF";
    try {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyStoreFile), password.toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(keyStore, password.toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);

        Hashtable<String, String> hashTable = new Hashtable<>();
        hashTable.put(PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
        hashTable.put(INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        hashTable.put(SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        hashTable.put(SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=MQRDP,ou=People,o=Administrators,dc=CS-Group,dc=com");
        hashTable.put(SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, providerCredentials);

        ic = new InitialContext(hashTable);
        connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup(queueManagerConnectionFactory);
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Exception while trying to connect to DEV OMB queue");
    }
    return connection;
}

private Session createSession() throws JMSException {
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return session;
}

private void init() throws JMSException {
    createConnection();
    createSession();
}

public void produceWorkflowMessage(String inboundControlMessageXML) throws JMSException {
    init();
    String destinationStr = "EDM.BIRS.RDP.S1.ONEPPM.TO_RDA";
    MessageProducer producer;
    Destination destination;
    try {
        destination = (Destination) ic.lookup("cn=" + destinationStr);
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(inboundControlMessageXML);
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        producer.send(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Exception occured while posting message to OMB topic");
        System.exit(1);
    } finally {
        session.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}

public static List<String> loadFromPropertiesFile(String propFileName) {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    List<String> workflowMessageList = null;
    try {
        Properties workflowProperties = new Properties();
        inputStream = ConstantClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
        if (inputStream != null) {
            workflowProperties.load(inputStream);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '"
                    + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        }
        workflowMessageList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String key : workflowProperties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            System.out.println("Key =" + key);
            String value = workflowProperties.getProperty(key);
            workflowMessageList.add(value);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error loading inboundxml worflow messages from properties file: " + e);
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out
                    .println("Exception while closing the file stream");
        }
    }
    return workflowMessageList;
}
```

}

Comment: Usually this happens when someone copies the details for the Dev managed object to define the SIT managed object.  Unfortunately, the one detail that specifies the object to which the code points -- the managed object definitions -- hasn't been provided.  Please update the question with that info.

Comment: @T.Rob  i dont understand when you mean managed objects. As i stated earlier we don have control over the IBM MQ messaging configuration and it is handled by the separate team. All we have is the connection details shared

Comment: The code is fetching connections and destinations using Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI).  The objects retrieved using the JNDI API are managed objects.  In the context of messaging, they are the means to map the Java specification which is generic to the transport vendor's specification which may be proprietary.  They encapsulate and abstract the proprietary details away so the app doesn't need to know (much) about the underlying JMS transport. It sounds like you have two managed objects pointing to the same MQ queue. @Calanais has provided diagnostic for this in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

This segment of code:

```
String destinationStr = "EDM.BIRS.RDP.S1.ONEPPM.TO_RDA";

Destination destination;
try {
    destination = (Destination) ic.lookup("cn=" + destinationStr);
```

is looking up the JMS Destination object from JNDI; in this case you've configured this as LDAP backed JNDI.  Note that the name that is being provided is the lookup name or queue that is being used index the Java object.. the actual Destination that is returned will be the control of whoever controls that LDAP/JNDI server.

Do a .toString() on the destination object and see what it is being resolved to. That will be actually where the message is being sent.

Be clear that the name supplied to lookup an object from JNDI is not the actual name of the Queue or Topic that is be used.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the configuration mismatch in the LDAP server by the external due to which the destination value returned was different.